# Show that $f(x) = \frac{\|x\|}{1 + \|x\|}$ has a minimum on $\mathbb{R^n}$, but no maximum on $\mathbb{R^n}.$

Tags: analysis

Show that $f(x) = \frac{\|x\|}{1 + \|x\|}$ has a minimum on $\mathbb{R^n}$, but no maximum on $\mathbb{R^n}.$

I was trying to show the existence of the minimum through differentiation criteria and for the maximum to assume by absurdity that it does exist, however that is cumbersome.

Comment: The minimum is $0$ as the numerator is at least $0$ and the denominator is at least $1$

Comment: xThe expression is bounded from above, (by 1), but the maximum is never acheived, because it is the limit as $\|x\| \to \infty$

Comment: Try it for $n=1$ first, and see how you can generalise what you've found for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound is straight-forward:
$$
0\leq f(x) \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
as well as 
$$
f(0)=0
$$
For the other part, note that 
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{1}{||x||+1}
$$
You can show that that $\sup f(x)=1$; however, this supremum is not attained.

Comment: How can I show that the $\sup{f(x)} =1$ s is not attained? , or that $f $ has no maximum.?

Comment: Just argue by contradiction. $f(x)=1$ implies $||x||=||x||+1$ which cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no differentiation needed.
If $x=0$, the function takes it‘s minimum value, because of non-negativity.
The function is bounded from above through
$\frac{\vert\lvert x \vert\rvert}{\vert\lvert x \vert\rvert}$.
The function itself doesn‘t take the value, because the denominator and nominator are not equal for any value of $x$.